# Why am I getting a "Change parameter type from list to boolean" when I try to insert values

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, mocking

I am mocking a service in springboot. I need to mock values for a request body. I keep getting error when I try to add a list of values.

```
This is the line of code:

XYZ xyz = new xyz().foo(new ArrayList<Foo>().add(new Foo().id("etfvgvhfhfjygj").check(Boolean.TRUE)))
```

```
Foo function:
public XYZ foo(List<@Valid Foo> foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    return this;
  }
```

Foo class has String id and Boolean check variables

`The error I get is: 'foo(java.util.List<abc.@jakarta.validation.Valid Foo>)' in 'abc.XYZ' cannot be applied to '(boolean)'`

I tried mocking the ArrayList but I am unable to figure out how to proceed.